# How do you connect to and manipulate an Azure SQL Database from a Service Fabric Stateless Service

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-sql-database

I'm completely new to Azure, and this feels like it should be quite obvious, but I've spent a good couple of days searching for documentation on this and can't find a single example of it being done, even though the documentation suggests it is a standard approach.

Following the documentation, I've created an empty SF project with a stateless service. I want to use it to perform the simple task of scraping a webpage every fortnight or so and storing a few links from it in a table.

I've used the Azure Portal to create an SQL Server, and have created a table and a schema via VS2015's SQL SOE, but how do I get the service to interact with it??

Comment: I actually wonder if the question is "Should you connect SF Stateless Services to SQL"?  Seeing as there are more "Azure scaling friendly" storage techniques such as Azure Table Storage.  If you do connect to SQL, do you sacrifice scaling potential of Service Fabric, because you are now tied to scaling SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use any technology you want. Like in any other .NET project type. There's [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556244.aspx), or plain [ADO.NET](https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/blog/msdn-article-how-to-connect-to-sql-azure-using-ado-net/). You could use [configuration](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-manage-multiple-environment-app-configuration/) to store your connection string. 
Also have a look at Actors and [Reminders](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-timers-reminders/). That could also be a simple technology to run your scheduled task.

Comment: Thanks! That was a push in the right direction, but I'm still quite puzzled. So what you're saying is that there are two methods to connect to Azure SQL: ADO.Net and EF. I've been trying to get some connection with both methods today and (not helped by the apparent lack of documentation) have come up short. For my attempt using EF, I roughly followed https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542, but end with the errors in event viewer that existing solutions online don't fix. Going down the ADO.Net way I think that I connect via connection strings? I'm still confused on where to put them.

Comment: Do you have any more pointers or samples you could send my way?

Comment: I'd recommend using EF. Maybe start by creating a local db first, using this walkthrough: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620  and when you're comfortable with the technology, move into azure. (example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg190738.aspx)  Plenty of EF documentation, start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg190738.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much @LoekD. Exactly what I needed to get started!

Comment: @LoekD Would I use JDBC for connecting to SQL databases from Stateless Reliable Service written in Java then? Also cannot find documentation about this.

Comment: it works the same as in any other java app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-java